# Understanding code of function strlen in C Programming

Tags: c, strlen

I was given a solution to the problem of recreating the function strlen in C Programming and it was the following, I need help understanding what the code is actually doing.

```
void    *ft_memset(void *b, int c, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        ((unsigned char *)b)[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    return (b);
}
```

My biggest doubts are the meaning of `((unsigned char *)b)[i] = c`, specially because I don't understand the `( *)b`, and the need for a return `b` in a `void` function.

Thank you very much for your help, sorry if I did something wrong its my first post in stack overflow.

Comment: That's not *strlen* :). And that "funny" thing from code is a pointer cast: from *void \** (a generic pointer - or memory address) to *unsigned char \** (which can be seen as a sequence of characters).

Comment: If this is an academic exercise, then perhaps you want to avoid looking at existing code, not even at code that is not `strlen`.

Comment: By the way the function you are looking at does not return  `void`.

Comment: @n.m. It's not *void* (the star is before the name).

Comment: Looks like `memset`, not `strlen` and the name `ft_memset` suggests it as well.

Comment: A `strlen (const char *s)` function can look like `size_t mystrlen (const char *s) { size_t len = 0; for (; s[len]; len++) {} return len; }` which will return the length of `s`. There is no assignment or copying involved. You are setting the first `len` characters in `b` to the character `c` in your function -- that's `memset()`.

Comment: strlen and memset have nothing in common so please clarify what you are doing...

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down, albeit my C skills are somewhat rusty. Edits are welcome :)

```c
void    *ft_memset(void *b, int c, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        ((unsigned char *)b)[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    return (b);
}
```

First, you have declared a function called `ft_memset` which returns `void *`.

`void *` means a pointer to any object. It's just a number, pointing to a memory address. But we do not know what's in it because it's not properly annotated.

Your function  takes three arguments:
`b` which is a pointer to *anything* (or void pointer if you will)
`c` which is an `int` 32-bit signed integer number.
`len` which is a `size_t`  which is usually an alias to an unsigned integer. [Read more about `size_t` over here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t)

---

Your function iterates through the first `len` bytes and sets the `c`'s value to those.

We're basically overwriting `b`'s contents for the first `len` bytes.

---

Now, what does `((unsigned char*)b)` mean. This statement is casting your `void *` to an `unsigned char*` (byte pointer), this is just
telling the compiler that we're gonna deal with the contents pointed by `b` as if they were just a `unsigned char`.

Later we're just indexing on the `i`-th position and setting the value `c` in it.

Comment: It's important to understand that memset deals with raw _bytes_, not array items.

Comment: <`void *` means a pointer to "anything"> better as <`void *` means a pointer to any object>,  Function pointers might not fit in a  `void *`.

Comment: Adding the edits as they come in <3

Comment: Does "it" in "it was just" refer to "contents pointed by `b`" (a plural - so use "they were just") or to "`b`" (singular)?

Comment: The first. I'll use the plural

Answer (score 1):

> Understanding code of function strlen

`void *ft_memset(void *b, int c, size_t len)` is like `void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n)`.  They both assign values to the memory pointed to by `b`.  These functions are quite different form `strlen()`.

`size_t strlen(const char *s)` does not alter the memory pointed to by `s`.  It iterates through that memory looking for a *null character*.

```
size_t strlen(const char *s) {
  const char *end = s;
  while (*end != '\0') {
    end++;
  }
  return (size_t)(end - s); 
}

// or

size_t strlen(const char *s) {
  size_t i = 0;
  while (s[i] != '\0') {
    i++;
  }
  return i; 
}
```